# C++ to C#: cin to Console.Read

Tags: c#, c++, console, iostream

Is there a way to read multiple inputs on the same line in C# like I would in C++?

I have included an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Format: name age"<< endl;
  int age;
  string name;
  cin >> name >> age;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is more a question of convenience oppose to splitting ReadLine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.Split` is the obvious solution here:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string [] split = input.Split(` `);
```

Then use the resultant array.

You lose your "nice" variable names and have to convert from `string` to `int` - but you'd have to do that anyway.

You can specify a set of split characters:

```
string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });
```

Comment: i think `cin >> name >> age` is more flexible, it splits string not by space only.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You have to implement this yourself using Console.Read or Console.ReadLine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [C# `std::cin` class](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/11/23/cin-class-for-csharp-read-from-console-nakov-io-cin/) written by [Svetlin Nakov](http://www.nakov.com) which behaves like `std::cin` in C++ and `java.util.Scanner`. It can read numbers, ints, doubles, decimals and string tokens from the console, just like `cin >> a >> b` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like this:

```
    var allInputs = Console.In
        .ReadToEnd()
        .Split(new string[] { " ", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    int argPtr = 0;

    var strPar1 = allInputs[argPtr++];
    var intPar2 = int.Parse(allInputs[argPtr++]);
    var strPar3 = allInputs[argPtr++];
    var intPar4 = int.Parse(allInputs[argPtr++]);
```